# Antlr4 Grammar issue (not entirely parsing)

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, antlr4, lexer

I am new to ANTLR and I am trying to get this grammar working:

```
grammar TemplateGrammar;

//Parser Rules 

start
    : block
    | statement
    | expression
    | parExpression
    | primary
    ;

block
    : LBRACE statement* RBRACE
    ;

statement
    : block
    | IF parExpression statement (ELSE statement)?
    | expression
    ;

parExpression
    : LPAREN expression RPAREN
    ;

expression
    : primary #PRIMARY
    | number op=('*'|'/') number            #MULDIV
    | number op=('+'|'-') number            #ADDSUB
    | number op=('>='|'<='|'>'|'<') number  #GRLWOREQUALS
    | expression op=('='|'!=') expression   #EQDIFF
    ;

primary
    :   parExpression
    |   literal
    ;

literal
    :   number  #NumberLiteral
    |   string  #StringLiteral
    |   columnName #ColumnNameLiteral
    ;

number
    :   DecimalIntegerLiteral       #DecimalIntegerLiteral
    |   DecimalFloatingPointLiteral #FloatLiteral
    ;

string
    :   '"' StringChars? '"'
    ;

columnName
    :   '[' StringChars? ']'
    ;

// Lexer Rules

//Integers
 DecimalIntegerLiteral
    :   DecimalNumeral
    ;

 fragment
 DecimalNumeral
    :   '0'
    |   NonZeroDigit (Digits? | Underscores Digits)
    ;

 fragment
 Digits
    :   Digit (DigitOrUnderscore* Digit)?
    ;

 fragment
 Digit
    :   '0'
    |   NonZeroDigit
    ;

 fragment
 NonZeroDigit
    :   [1-9]
    ;

 fragment
 DigitOrUnderscore
    :   Digit
    |   '_'
    ;

 fragment
 Underscores
    :   '_'+
    ;

//Floating point
DecimalFloatingPointLiteral
    :   Digits '.' Digits? ExponentPart?
    |   '.' Digits ExponentPart?
    |   Digits ExponentPart
    |   Digits
    ;

fragment
ExponentPart
    :   ExponentIndicator SignedInteger
    ;

fragment
ExponentIndicator
    :   [eE]
    ;

fragment
SignedInteger
    :   Sign? Digits
    ;

fragment
Sign
    :   [+-]
    ;

//Strings

StringChars
    :   StringChar+
    ;

fragment
StringChar
    :   ~["\\]
    |   EscapeSequence
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   '\\' [btnfr"'\\]
    ;

//Separators
LPAREN          : '(';
RPAREN          : ')';
LBRACE          : '{';
RBRACE          : '}';
LBRACK          : '[';
RBRACK          : ']';
COMMA           : ',';
DOT             : '.';

//Keywords
IF              : 'IF';
ELSE            : 'ELSE';
THEN            : 'THEN';

//Operators
PLUS            : '+';
MINUS           : '-';
MULTIPLY        : '*';
DIVIDE          : '/';
EQUALS          : '=';
DIFFERENT       : '!=';
GRTHAN          : '>';
GROREQUALS      : '>=';
LWTHAN          : '<';
LWOREQUALS      : '<=';
AND             : '&';
OR              : '|';

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ -> skip ;
```

When I put `"Test"` in the input, it is working and returning the String `"Test"`.

Here is what I get in the `IParseTree` when I put `"Test"` in the input:

> "(start (statement (expression (primary (literal (string \" Test \"))))))"

But when I put `[Test]` (wich is almost the same as `"Test"` but with braces instead of quotes), the parser does not recognize the token...

Here is the `IParseTree` I get when I put `[Tree]`:

> "(start [Test])"

Same with numbers, it does well recognize lonely numbers such as `1`, `123`, `12.5`, etc. but not expressions like `1+2`...

Do you have any idea why the parser isn't recognizing `columnNames` rule but does work well with the `string` rule?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because "StringChar" is defined incorrectly for your purpose? It doesn't handle "]"

Perhaps you want to define StringChar as:

```
fragment
StringChar
:   ~["\\\]]
|   EscapeSequence
;
```

If it were my grammar, I'd define a QuotedStringChar as you have for quoted strings, and define BracketStringChar as  **~[\]\\]** to use for your bracket column names.

Welcome to debugging grammars at the lexical level, and defining different types of "quotes" for different types of strings.  This is pretty common. (You should see Ruby, where you can define the string quote at the beginning of the string, ick.).

Comment: I deleted the fragments `StringChar` and `EscapeSequence` and replaced `StringChars` by: `[A-Za-z0-9]+`. It works better for the recognition of columnNames but doesn't match String containing only numbers such as `"123"`. I'll try your solution :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that your solution is not working for strings like `"Test"` nor for columnNames like `[Test]` :/

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly got it working by putting:

```
QuotedStringChars
    :   '"' ~[\"]+ '"'
    ;

BracketStringChars
    :   '[' ~[\]]+ ']'
    ;
```

To take any characters between quotes or brackets. Then :

```
primary
    :   literal #PrimLiteral
    |   number  #PrimNumber
    ;

literal
    :   QuotedStringChars   #OneString
    |   BracketStringChars  #ColumnName
    |   number              #NUMBER
    ;

number
    :   DecimalIntegerLiteral       #DecimalIntegerLiteral
    |   DecimalFloatingPointLiteral #FloatLiteral
    ;
```

The `literal` rule helps to distinguish quoted string, bracket string and numbers.

There is a duplication of `number` in `primary` and `literal` rules because I need a different behavior in my application for each one.

I managed this with the good advices of Ira Baxter :)

> Hope this will help other newbies to ANTLR like me to have a better
>   understanding :)

Comment: So you agree with my assessment that you needed to include "]" in the set of not-string-characters.   Explain why you believe that you need to have "[" in that set. Also, explain why you had to hand numbers as a special case; surely 0-9 is accepted by the not-string-characters in exactly the same way as A-Z.   Without these explanations, I don't think this will help other ANTLR newbies.

Comment: Well, if the input is `[[Test]` it will still return `Test` so that is okay.
I don't really get why I had to handle numbers as a special case but when I tested the `[123]` input, the parser didn't recognize the `123` sequence. With the numbers as a special case, it works like a charm.

Comment: If you don't get "why", you don't understand what you did and need to spend more time on it.  When programming/debugging, if it isn't extremely clear to why your solution works, then it probably doesn't really work, or it works for the wrong reasons.   I'm not going to debug your grammar for you, but I beleive the need for a separate specifications for numbers is nonsense.  (That's why I don't think this answer is helpful to other ANTLR newbies).

Comment: I never said that I fully understood the grammar, just that it was working and I understood at least the escaping part in the StringChars. When I debug the parsing of the input `[123]` it crashes at `start()` with an `Antlr4.Runtime.NoViableAltException` and I don't get why...

Comment: So... you have more work to do until you *do* understand it.

Comment: Yes, of course, I only began learning ANTLR last week. But at least with my solution, I'm getting the right strings from quoted strings and bracket strings. When I will understand why the numbers are not getting parsed, I will improve it but until there I can't do much...

Comment: I suggest you strip the grammar down until all that is left is the strings part, and then experiment with it until you find out what is funny.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thank you, I finally got it and edited my answer :)

Comment: More good advices(?): 1: I'm still puzzled by your continued use of a digit-string recognizer, now in the rule named "literal".  I'm unconvinced you need it.  2: We can argue about why you would include "\[" in the antiset; that allows a columnname to contain its quote character, whereas onestring cannot contain its quote character. yes, you can define it that way.  It violates the *principle of least surprise"; you shoud design a language to be as intuitive as possible.  Your scheme also has the odd property that a column name cannot contain a """ character.  What else should it not contain?

Comment: Here you are talking about the specifications and intuitiveness of the language wich is a "dummy" language just created for my learning. So yes, I am aware of your remarks but the original question was about how to to parse quoted strings and brackets strings independantly, wich is well done with that grammar :) Once again, thanks for your remarks and advices :)